# How to write program run matrix as below in python?

Tags: python

Thanks for everyone's reply. I will explain here.
Suppose there is a given matrix

```
    x                  y                B = [5,-4,5,-6]
[[0,0,0,0],        [[0,1,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0],         [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],         [0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0]]         [0,0,0,0]]
```

for example a feasible solution is [[0,4,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0]]  4+1-0 == 5 0-4 == -4 5-0 == 5 0 - 5-1 == -6

I want to update x to make sure:

```
 (1) if y[i][j] == 0:
       x[i][j] = 0
   (2) x[0][0]+x[0][1]+x[0][2]+x[0][3]-x[0][0]-x[1][0]-x[2][0]-x[3][0] = B[0]
       x[1][0]+x[1][1]+x[1][2]+x[1][3]-x[0][1]-x[1][1]-x[2][1]-x[3][1] = B[1]
       ...
```

How to program to find the feasible x?

Comment: Why did initialize the x with all 0s?

Comment: To make sure it is a 4*4 matrix. I am bigner, could you help me ?

Comment: its not very clear what you are asking for

Comment: Eh, I just want to find the feasible solution just like  [[0,4,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0]]. 4+1-0 == 5  0-4 == -4  5-0 == 5 0 - 5-1 == -6

Comment: This still makes zero sense

Comment: @RenanGemignani You mean x will always be zero?

Comment: @wesley, Are you trying to row reduce (RREF) a 4 by 4 matrix? It is very unclear what you're asking. You keep saying "find the feasible solution just like ...", but that doesn't explain much. What is the overall goal? Is there an online resource or example you could point to?

Comment: No, he means that we still don't understand what your actual question is. What problem are you having? We don't know how to help you find a solution if you don't tell us why *you* can't find a solution.

Comment: Rather, if we don't know what problem you want to solve we can't help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer updated, i wrote some code to parse variables.

```
B = [5,-4,5,-6]
y = [
        [0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0],
    ]
x = []
for i, row in enumerate(y):
    temp = []
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        if col != 0:
            temp.append(str(col) + '*x' + str(i) + str(j))
        else:
            temp.append(col)
    x.append(temp)

#for one in x:
#    print one


equ = []
for i in xrange(4):
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []
    for j in xrange(4):
        temp1.append(x[i][j])
        temp2.append(x[j][i])
    temp2.append(B[i])
    equ.append(tuple(temp1 + temp2))

equtions = []
for one in equ:
    s = '%s + %s + %s + %s - %s - %s - %s - %s = %s' % one
    equtions.append(s)

for one in equtions:
    print one

import re
from copy import deepcopy

equ_bak = deepcopy(equtions)

p_var = re.compile(r'x\d\d')
vars = set([])
for one in equ_bak:
    m = p_var.findall(one)
    vars |= set(m)
vars = sorted(list(vars))

p_ef = re.compile(r'([+-]* *\d*)\*(x\d\d)')
effs = []
for one in equ_bak:
    m = p_ef.findall(one)
    #print m
    temp = [0] * len(vars)
    for num, var in m:
        try:
            temp[vars.index(var)] = float(num.replace(' ', ''))
        except:
            pass
    effs.append(tuple(temp))

#for one in effs:
#    print one

import numpy as np
A = np.array(effs)
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A,B)
print vars
print x[0]
```

Comment: @wesley: The answer can not sovle every problem.