# How to find x to make sure sum(row[i])-sum(clo[i])=bi in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a matix

```
x = [[0,x01,x02,x03],
     [x10,0,x12,0],
     [x20,x21,0,x23],
     [x30,0,x32,0]]
x[i][j]>=0
b = [5,-4,5,-6]
```

I am looking for an easy way to find out one value for x to make sure that

```
x[i][0]+x[i][1]+x[i][2]+x[i][3]-x[0][i]-x[1][i]-x[2][i]-x[3][i] == b[i]
```

I have tried many methods, but all failed. 
Possible answer is like

```
 x = [[0,4,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,5],
     [0,0,0,0]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a linear programming problem. Finding all possible values of `x` that satisfy the constraints is probably a bad idea; there may be infinitely many, or a crazy huge number of them if you restrict entries to integers. Finding one value that works should be simple enough, though.

Comment: Just one value is OK.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Show us one of your approaches so we could help to fix/improve it.

Comment: You could look into linear programming solvers such as [PuLP](https://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/) or [Pyomo](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/wiki/Pyomo), or implement the simplex method yourself if you want, or just do the math by hand if you only need to solve the problem for these specific parameters.

Comment: It's worth noting that your problem leaves the diagonal of the matrix unconstrained, since for each `i`, you'll be both adding and subtracting `x[i][i]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write program run matrix as below in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795560/how-to-write-program-run-matrix-as-below-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set some constrains or you will get multiple solutions as @Blckknght pointed out. But hard code some stuff to get it work is easy, just some matrix manipulations.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> from scipy import optimize
>>> def f1(p, b=array([5,-4,5,-6])):
    mp=matrix(array(p).reshape((4,4))) #or reshape((b.size, b.size))
    return sum(array(dot(mp-mp.T, array([1,1,1,1]))-b)**2) #or ones((b.size,))

>>> optimize.fmin(f1, range(16))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 467
         Function evaluations: 743
array([  8.55102418e-04,   1.19481331e+00,   9.84510105e-01,
         3.42579838e+00,   3.37327593e+00,   3.95448146e+00,
         1.18750846e+01,   8.73475559e+00,   5.64496730e+00,
         9.28651143e+00,   9.33505858e+00,   1.59977154e+01,
        -8.41311844e+00,   1.75017928e+01,   1.30696514e+01,
         1.46774131e+01])
```

There must be some better way to do it, but to constrain the values to `int` can be done with very little change:

```
>>> def f1(p, b=array([5,-4,5,-6])):
    mp=matrix(array(p).round().reshape((4,4))) #or reshape((b.size, b.size))
    return sum(array(dot(mp-mp.T, array([1,1,1,1]))-b)**2) #or ones((b.size,))

>>> rlist=[]
>>> for i in range(-500, 500): #constrain to a desired range, and just get the one of the possible answers
    q=optimize.fmin(f1, range(i, i+16), disp=False).round()
    rlist.append((q, f1(q)))
    if f1(q)==0:
        break   
>>> rlist[-1]
(array([-501., -498., -495., -493., -497., -499., -494., -492., -496.,
        -491., -494., -487., -498., -490., -490., -489.]), 0.0)

>>> rlist[-1][0].reshape((4,4))
array([[-501., -498., -495., -493.],
       [-497., -499., -494., -492.],
       [-496., -491., -494., -487.],
       [-498., -490., -490., -489.]])
```

Strictly speaking they are still `float` but that's ok. Use `_int()` to convert.

Comment: I want to get the intgers.

Comment: How can I make sure they are all integers?

Comment: Thank you very much!  @CT Zhu  My email address is weilizhang@gmail.com，I have some questions about the code, can you send me your email?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake about the email address, weilizhang1989@gmail.com